# Uploading a .rar file

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

This is my case: A user uploads a .rar file containing multiple files.

The **.rar** file is shown and downloadable.

But how to implement a function on the front end that would show the .rar file to be downloaded with a link (the whole file) and then all child files in the .rar could be shown for download also (one at a time)?

Here is what the output would look like on the front end:

```
   These files are available for download:

   -[link]raredfile.rar   (linked to download: the whole rar file)
      -[link]file 1       (linked to download: file 1 in the .rar file)
      -[link]file 2       (linked to download: file 2 in the .rar file)
```

Is is possible? If so could you give me some pointers what to use and how?

Thank you for answering.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Upload the .rar

upload your .rar file.
  store on a folder: 
  example:

project/files/rar.rar

### 2. Extract .rar

extract your .rar file.
now you should have 2 files with the same name:

`project/files/rar.rar` - rar file
`project/files/rar/` - folder

### 3. Downloading the files

now you can display all the contents of the folder using a backend language.
example:

```
  <a href="project/files/rar.rar">raredfile.rar</a>  (linked to download: the whole rar file)
  - <a href="project/files/rar/file1.txt">file 1</a>   (linked to download: file 1 in the .rar file)
  - <a href="project/files/rar/file2.txt">file 2</a>  (linked to download: file 2 in the .rar file)
```

Comment: How do I combine this when te file is uploaded to a folder on a server? And then the files are searched through a MySQL database?

Comment: Is it possible to automate this on the server somehow? or must I do it manually?

Comment: @iNejc you do not need MySQL for these just name the file with your primary key. and yes the `extract` after upload can be automated.

Comment: @iNejc btw are you also using PHP?

Comment: can i see your php code for uploading the `.rar` files?